# flutter access reusable widget data

Tags: dart, flutter

i just start to learn flutter and something confusing me, as the picture below I created a reusable widget - a row that contain 2 dropdown menu which is month and year. When I import and use it in another widget then i have no idea how i can access the selected Month and selected Year from the reusable widget.

```
class MonthYearPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MonthYearPickerState createState() => _MonthYearPickerState();
}

class _MonthYearPickerState extends State<MonthYearPicker> {
  List<DropdownMenuItem> monthList = const [
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('January'), value: 1),
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('February'), value: 2)
  ];

final List<DropdownMenuItem> yearList = [
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text((DateTime.now().year - 2).toString()), value: -2),
    DropdownMenuItem(child: Text((DateTime.now().year).toString()), value: 0),
  ];

  int _selectedMonth;
  int _selectedYear;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        DropdownButton(
          items: monthList,
          value: _selectedMonth,
          hint: Text('---Month---'),
      onChanged: (value) {
            _selectedMonth = value;
            setState(() {});
          },
    ),
        DropdownButton(
      items: yearList,
          value: _selectedYear,
          hint: Text('---Year---'),
          onChanged: (value) {
        _selectedYear = value;
            setState(() {});
          },
    ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

code below is how i import and use the widget from another .dart file

```
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
        MonthYearPicker(),
            Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Get Date'),
            onPressed: () {
              //How to access selected month and year from MonthYearPicker?
                },
          ),
        )
          ],
```

[reusable row of dropdown button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky8B8.png)

[import and use in another file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G4E8.png)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a callback that called on on Change method like

```
MonthYearPicker((picked){
 setState((){_pickedMonth = picked});
}
```

So inside the onChanged

```
onChanged: handlePickedMonth;
```